# How to clear localStorage in UWP javascript app?

Tags: javascript, uwp

I store some data inside local storage in my JavaScript UWP app: `localStorage.setItem("myKey", "myValue")`. My app extracts stored data on start up.

I need to perform "clean" start up, when nothing stored inside local storage. How I can clean app cache (including local storage) on Windows 10 Desktop?

I know how I can do this using JavaScript code. But I need to clear it using system tools. I believe it possible.

Comment: If you want to clean that I think you will need use the temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clean the data by using system tools on Windows 10 Desktop, you should be able to open the Settings app, and reset a desired app.

Here’s how to do that:

1. Open Settings
2. Go to System > Apps & features
3. Find an app you want to reset, and click on Advanced options
4. Click the Reset button

But we can not run it in our apps, we should be able to launch the Settings and let the user to choose the app that he want to reset.

If you want clean the data without users choosing, you should be able to do this using JavaScript code.